# How would one go about implementing scripts into LibGDX?

Tags: java, lua, scripting, libgdx

I am making an RPG game in libGDX and have been reading about how to implement quest systems and a lot of people are telling me to use a scripting language such as LUA or Javascript.

I have never used a scripting language before and am curious about how exactly I would program my game to read them. I've looked for tutorials online but there doesn't seem to be any good ones that explain how to get started. 
Could someone point me in the right direction on how to get started? Thanks.

Comment: Why they are telling you this is that it allows you to easily create new quests.
However, as @eldo pointed it out, this is not really related to the libGDX framework but rather a general question.
Using a scripting language is not mandatory at all.
If you want to find information about how to implement a quest system, you can begin with this http://larc.unt.edu/ian/pubs/pcg2011.pdf

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any special task that would require using anything other than java. LibGDX and its friends covers everything you will need when working on an RPG game.

Using scene2D its fast and easy to set up your scenes stages and actors. With TMX support you can load your map in minutes.

There is Box2D for an easily manageable physics world.

Provides easy to use file handling system: 
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling

And there is gdxAI: https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-ai
With features like: Movement AI,
Steering Behaviors,
Formation Motion,
Pathfinding,
A*,
Hierarchical Pathfinding,
Path Smoothing,
Interruptible Pathfinding,
Decision Making,
State Machine,
Behavior Trees,
Infrastructure,
Message Handling,
Scheduling,

And still a lot more. LibGdx is huge and provides everything you need.